# Using gitattributes for linguist examples

Tags: github, gitattributes, github-linguist

Are there any concrete examples, in order to detect wrong languages in GitHub via Linguist attributes?

Source: https://github.com/github/linguist

- linguist-documentation
- linguist-language
- linguist-vendored

Comment: They can be found in the `README.md` - https://github.com/github/linguist/tree/47b109be3657fe3d5933fba6840a6ceea0f94498#overrides - Although I'd admit it's not very easy to find.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Examples can be found in [Linguist's documentation](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/overrides.md#using-gitattributes).
Detecting wrong languages (which's what OP asks) can be achieved by setting `linguist-language` attributes in the `.gitattributes` file.

**linguist-language**

With the following attribute, Linguist detects all `.rb` files as being Java files.

```
*.rb linguist-language=Java
```

**linguist-vendored**

With the following attribute, Linguist detects files in the `special-vendored-path` directory (notice the mandatory trailing `*`) as *vendored* and excludes them from statistics.

```
special-vendored-path/* linguist-vendored
```

A double `*` will also apply the override to all subdirectories:

```
 special-vendored-path/** linguist-vendored
```

**linguist-documentation**

**Without** the following attribute, Linguist would detect the file `docs/formatter.rb` as *documentation* and exclude it from statistics.

```
docs/formatter.rb linguist-documentation=false
```

**linguist-detectable**

With the following attribute, Linguist counts SQL files in statistics. Without this attribute, only programming and markup languages are counted in statistics.

```
*.sql linguist-detectable=true
```

Comment: Is it also possible to do `* linguist-detectable=true` to show every single language?

Comment: @DaCuteRaccoon Yes, I'd expect that to work.