# Overriding GitHub linguist for project named demo

Tags: github

The root folder for my project is named `demo` and I'm trying to override it by adding a `.gitattributes` at the same level as the directory.

I have tried:

```
demo/** linguist-documentation
```

This doesn't seem to work, however.

What should I include instead so that the linguist will scan my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `.gitattributes` directives mentioned in "[Using gitattributes for linguist examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43142088/6309)"

None of those includes the name of the repository, only folders/files inside the repository. See more at "[ithub/linguist/blob Overrides / Using gitattributes](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/overrides.md#using-gitattributes)"

In your case:

```
** linguist-documentation=false
```